# How to caulk stone backsplash to granite countertop?

Tags: kitchen-counters, caulking, stone, backsplash, transition

My kitchen has a stone backsplash and granite countertops.  In some places there is a gap between the two, as illustrated below.

[image]

I would like to seal this gap to prevent moisture from getting behind the wall.  Is a silcone-based kitchen caulk appropriate for this application?  This backsplash was put in by the previous owner of the home and I am unfamiliar with the techniques and tools used to seal it.  The areas that have no gap appear to have some sort of stone seal, like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a sanded caulk.  The big box stores have these in their tile areas.  I would find something that matches your backsplash grout.